# Is being thankful for Jesus' death biblical?

Tags: biblical-basis, life-of-jesus, crucifixion

Are there any examples in the Bible of people being thankful that Jesus died, or promoting the practice of thanking God/Jesus for Jesus' death? I'm asking specifically about his death, not life or resurrection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but it's not for the death *per se*, as though the death has its intrinsic value, but for **the meaning** of Jesus's death, the immensity of **WHO** died and for what Jesus's death **effected in us**:

1. Death as expression of the love that Jesus has shown us, by giving up his life for his friend (John 15:13-14)
2. Death as the eternal Passover Lamb that God has provided to become the means for taking away the sins of the world (John 1:29)
3. Death as God's declaring the end of the power of sin's control over us by sending His Son Jesus to become the humanity's representative through incarnation (Rom 8:3)
4. Death (and the attendant suffering) showing that God is truly with us in solidarity with our suffering instead of watching us suffer from a distance.
5. Etc.

As for examples in the Bible of people being thankful of Jesus's death in the meaning explained above, we can cite

1. **Paul**, in many places of his letters, such as Eph 1:6-7, where although the word "thanksgiving" or "gratitude" doesn't appear in the pericope (Eph 1:3-8), it's very clear from the text that he is thankful.  Eph 1:6-7:

   > <sup>6</sup> So **we praise God** for the glorious grace he has poured out on us who belong to his dear Son. <sup>7</sup> He is so rich in kindness and grace that he purchased our freedom **with the blood of his Son** and forgave our sins.
2. **The author of Hebrews**, asking us to respond with acts of love and good works (Heb 10:24) in response to our being sprinkled (purified) with Christ's blood (Heb 10:22).  Later in the book, Heb 13:15-16, the preacher invites us to offer "sacrifice of praise to God" (which implicitly include thanksgiving) for Jesus's blood sanctifying us (Heb 13:12), which Christians incorporate in the celebration of the Lord's supper.

Comment: The reference to John 15:13-14 says it all. The manner of Christ's death is the proof of his love and offer of friendship. Friendship with God is the most precious commodity in the universe and its offer the thing most to be grateful for.

Comment: In effect, we are thankful to Jesus for offering himself, while feeling guilty about the necessity. Would that be a fair comment?

Comment: @StephenDisraeli I think we should feel guilty for our sins and in response to the grace received, we unite ourselves with Christ in his death by also offering our lives to those we love (including enemies!) as a sacrifice for God.  That way, we move on from guilt to love.  I got your point about guilty about the necessity since that's the predominant undercurrent (although may not be intentional) of how Christ's death is preached from the evangelical pulpits.

Comment: @StephenDisraeli But I have since emphasized **incarnation** as necessity because our broken desires that lead to sin in the first place need to be healed. We are not just made righteous but also made into conformity with the image of Christ (theosis).  Death on the cross doesn't only justify, we also drink his blood to get his life flowing in our new life (sanctification). Thinking of Jesus' death as healing agent by a long-suffering shepherd will then dampen the guilt aspect just like we are more thankful of our parents's patience than feeling guilty, although they did suffer for us.

Answer (score 3):

The memorial of the Lord's supper, instituted by Jesus himself and proscribed by the apostle Paul is a remembrance, perpetually, until Christ returns.

> 23For I have received of the Lord that which also I delivered unto you, That the Lord Jesus the same night in which he was betrayed took bread: 24And when he had given thanks, he brake it, and said, Take, eat: this is my body, which is broken for you: this do in remembrance of me. 25After the same manner also he took the cup, when he had supped, saying, This cup is the new testament in my blood: this do ye, as oft as ye drink it, in remembrance of me. 26For as often as ye eat this bread, and drink this cup, ye do shew **the Lord's death** till he come. [1 Corinthians 11 KJV]

'Ye do shew the Lord's death (specifically) till he come'.

The remembrance and the 'shewing' of the death of the Lord Jesus is surely a matter of thanksgiving.

Answer (score 3):

**Is being thankful for Jesus' death biblical?**

The short answer is **yes**.

One of the popular verses people like to quote is [John 3:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203%3A16&version=KJV). “For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.” Let us always be aware that St. Paul reminds us to give thanks to God for everything in our lives. This should include Jesus’ Passion and Death on the Cross. The gift of Jesus’ death on the Cross opened heaven for humanity. He took our place and gave us eternal life life. He freely died for our salvation; how can we not be give thanks to God the Father for such a gift. “In every thing give thanks: for this is the will of God in Christ Jesus concerning you.” [(1 Thessalonians 5:18)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Thessalonians%205%3A18&version=KJV)

Jesus himself gave us the example to follow on the night before his Passion. Now if Jesus commanded us to commemorate the Last Supper in thanksgiving; should we not also give thanks for his Passion and Death?

> 18 For I tell you that from now on I will not drink of the fruit of the vine until the kingdom of God comes.” 19 And he took bread, and when he had given thanks, he broke it and gave it to them, saying, “This is my body, which is given for you. Do this in remembrance of me.” 20 And likewise the cup after they had eaten, saying, “This cup that is poured out for you is the new covenant in my blood. - [Luke 22:18-20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2014%3A22-25%2CLuke%2022%3A18-20%2C1%20Corinthians%2011%3A23-25&version=ESV)

Let us there give Thanks to God with tearful joy in Christ’s triumph over sin and opening heaven for a humanity with a fallen nature.

> Feeling and expressing appreciation is good for us. Like any wise father, God wants us to learn to be thankful for all the gifts He has given us (James 1:17). It is in our best interest to be reminded that everything we have is a gift from Him. Without gratitude, we become arrogant and self-centered. We begin to believe that we have achieved everything on our own. Thankfulness keeps our hearts in right relationship to the Giver of all good gifts. - [Why is giving thanks to God important?](https://www.gotquestions.org/giving-thanks-to-God.html)

Here is one prayer of thanksgiving for Jesus dying for us, I found online:

> "Dear Jesus, Thank You for dying on the cross for our sins so that we may live. Thank You for Your love and Your provisions, and for the call You have placed on our lives. Thank You for planting a seed within us, so that the desire to know You more, and the desire to follow You, will grow deep. We worship, and praise You. Holy Spirit, We thank You for fighting our battles, You are amazing in all wisdom, knowledge and understanding. We ask for all of You. May we walk with You and speak Your words constantly knowing it’s not us but You within us. Be with us and guide us through this day, we thank You Father, Son and Holy Spirit. Amen" - [Strong Women For Christ](https://quozio.com/quote/a5afe6b2/1025/dear-jesusthank-you-for-dying-on-the-cross-for-our-sins-so)